# how to use ajax call with jQuery toggle button

Tags: jquery, ajax, onclick, jsonp, odoo

I am working with OpenERP-odoo module.

In which toggle button is used to display publish-unpublish on click.
on each click there is some background process to **fetch data using json rpc**

I want to `.hide()` this toggle button for the duration while background process [Inshort: i dont want to toggle this button instantly]

```
​        $(document).on('click', '.js_publish_management .js_publish_btn', function () {
            var $data = $(this).parents(".js_publish_management:first");
            var self=this;
            openerp.jsonRpc($data.data('controller') || '/website/publish', 'call', {'id': +$data.data('id'), 'object': $data.data('object')})
                .then(function (result) {
                    $data.toggleClass("css_unpublished css_published");
                    $data.parents("[data-publish]").attr("data-publish", +result ? 'on' : 'off');
                }).fail(function (err, data) {
                    website.error(data, '/web#return_label=Website&model='+$data.data('object')+'&id='+$data.data('id'));
                });
        });
```

I am not familiar with Ajax call. can anybody guide me! TIA.

Comment: can't i handle this with success and error method, as i referred w3schools.. thats why i am asking

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
            $('.btn-group').ready( function () {
                $('.btn-group').button('loading');
                openerp.jsonRpc($data.data('controller') || '/website/publish', 'call', {'id': +$data.data('id'), 'object': $data.data('object')})
                    .then(function (result) {
                        $data.toggleClass("css_unpublished css_published");
                        //do something
                        $('.btn-group').button('reset');
                    }).fail(function (err, data) {
                        //do something
                        $('.btn-group').button('reset');
                    });
            });
```

you can try to use bootstrap ready class to display 'loading..' status instead

Answer (score 1):

in the first line of your function call `.hide()` on your element. Then in the ajax call add in the `.always()` function to show it:

```
 $(document).on('click', '.js_publish_management .js_publish_btn', function () {
     var $data = $(this).parents(".js_publish_management:first");
     var self=this;

     //hide your element here
     element.hide();

     openerp.jsonRpc($data.data('controller') || '/website/publish', 'call', {'id': +$data.data('id'), 'object': $data.data('object')})
         .then(function (result) {
         $data.toggleClass("css_unpublished css_published");
         $data.parents("[data-publish]").attr("data-publish", +result ? 'on' : 'off');
         }).fail(function (err, data) {
             website.error(data, '/web#return_label=Website&model='+$data.data('object')+'&id='+$data.data('id'));
         }).always(function(){
             //show your element again. Once the call is resolved either way
             element.show();
         });
    });
```

Comment: .always is ajax or jQuery function? asking for just knowledge

Comment: and can't i handle this with success and error method, as i referred w3schools.. thats why i am asking

Comment: `.always()` is jquery. Yes you could add the `element.show()` to both the success and error methods.

Comment: thanks @craicerjack  is it correct??                                                                                                              $.ajax({url:'/website/publish', {
                success: function(data) {
                    $('.btn-group').show();

                },
                error: function() {
                    $('.btn-group').hide();
                }

Comment: @testerr correct except you want to show the button in both functions. Well at least I thought you did. You are hiding the button once clicked and then showing it once resolved. If you dont show it in the error function itll just dissappear for good if there is an error in the ajax.    
`$.ajax({url:'/website/publish', { success: function(data) { $('.btn-group').show(); }, error: function() { $('.btn-group').show(); }`